# Preview stripe subscription price change with coupon

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on subscriptions for a project and want to be able to show the end-user what they will owe today (prorated difference if upgrading) and what they will pay monthly moving forward. This part is pretty straight forward but the issue comes when I want to also have the user upgrade and apply a new coupon code.

I am submitting the coupon to the Stripe invoices.retrieveUpcoming API and the object that is returned has discount information on it but the line items don't show the discounted prices.

Here is an example output from the API call:

```
{
    "object": "invoice",
    "account_country": "US",
    "account_name": "MPACT Assessment",
    "account_tax_ids": null,
    "amount_due": 8950,
    "amount_paid": 0,
    "amount_remaining": 8950,
    "application_fee_amount": null,
    "attempt_count": 0,
    "attempted": false,
    "billing_reason": "upcoming",
    "charge": null,
    "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
    "created": 1619725969,
    "currency": "usd",
    "custom_fields": null,
    "customer": "cus_J9130PfYbywDY7",
    "customer_address": null,
    "customer_email": "testylittletester@gmail.com",
    "customer_name": "Testy Tester",
    "customer_phone": null,
    "customer_shipping": null,
    "customer_tax_exempt": "none",
    "customer_tax_ids": [],
    "default_payment_method": null,
    "default_source": null,
    "default_tax_rates": [],
    "description": null,
    "discount": {
        "id": "di_1IaR98G7MnKgivLUT7aFESCe",
        "object": "discount",
        "checkout_session": null,
        "coupon": {
            "id": "test_coupon50",
            "object": "coupon",
            "amount_off": null,
            "created": 1616428624,
            "currency": null,
            "duration": "forever",
            "duration_in_months": null,
            "livemode": true,
            "max_redemptions": null,
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "Test Coupon",
            "percent_off": 50,
            "redeem_by": null,
            "times_redeemed": 19,
            "valid": true
        },
        "customer": "cus_J9130PfYbywDY7",
        "end": null,
        "invoice": "in_1IaR98G7MnKgivLUhmyyoJUi",
        "invoice_item": null,
        "promotion_code": null,
        "start": 1617047590,
        "subscription": null
    },
    "discounts": [
        "di_1IaR98G7MnKgivLUT7aFESCe"
    ],
    "due_date": null,
    "ending_balance": 0,
    "footer": null,
    "last_finalization_error": null,
    "lines": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "il_tmp1IaR98G7MnKgivLU7VWoVDNL",
                "object": "line_item",
                "amount": -2900,
                "currency": "usd",
                "description": "Unused time on Teams Dashboard after 29 Mar 2021",
                "discount_amounts": [
                    {
                        "amount": 0,
                        "discount": "di_1IaR98G7MnKgivLUT7aFESCe"
                    }
                ],
                "discountable": false,
                "discounts": [],
                "invoice_item": "ii_1IaR98G7MnKgivLU7VWoVDNL",
                "livemode": true,
                "metadata": {},
                "period": {
                    "end": 1619725969,
                    "start": 1617047590
                },
                "plan": {
                    "id": "teams_starter030421",
                    "object": "plan",
                    "active": true,
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "amount": 2900,
                    "amount_decimal": "2900",
                    "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                    "created": 1614974026,
                    "currency": "usd",
                    "interval": "month",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "livemode": true,
                    "metadata": {
                        "maxTeams": "3"
                    },
                    "nickname": "Starter Teams Dashboard",
                    "product": "prod_J3PgxhjcFS5hSY",
                    "tiers_mode": null,
                    "transform_usage": null,
                    "trial_period_days": null,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "price": {
                    "id": "teams_starter030421",
                    "object": "price",
                    "active": true,
                    "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                    "created": 1614974026,
                    "currency": "usd",
                    "livemode": true,
                    "lookup_key": null,
                    "metadata": {
                        "maxTeams": "3"
                    },
                    "nickname": "Starter Teams Dashboard",
                    "product": "prod_J3PgxhjcFS5hSY",
                    "recurring": {
                        "aggregate_usage": null,
                        "interval": "month",
                        "interval_count": 1,
                        "trial_period_days": null,
                        "usage_type": "licensed"
                    },
                    "tiers_mode": null,
                    "transform_quantity": null,
                    "type": "recurring",
                    "unit_amount": 2900,
                    "unit_amount_decimal": "2900"
                },
                "proration": true,
                "quantity": 1,
                "subscription": "sub_JCqq4Pb9LCeqPt",
                "subscription_item": "si_JCqqKM0mNJwXqR",
                "tax_amounts": [],
                "tax_rates": [],
                "type": "invoiceitem"
            },
            {
                "id": "il_tmp1IaR98G7MnKgivLUFy2gEVp3",
                "object": "line_item",
                "amount": 7900,
                "currency": "usd",
                "description": "Remaining time on Teams Dashboard after 29 Mar 2021",
                "discount_amounts": [
                    {
                        "amount": 0,
                        "discount": "di_1IaR98G7MnKgivLUT7aFESCe"
                    }
                ],
                "discountable": false,
                "discounts": [],
                "invoice_item": "ii_1IaR98G7MnKgivLUFy2gEVp3",
                "livemode": true,
                "metadata": {},
                "period": {
                    "end": 1619725969,
                    "start": 1617047590
                },
                "plan": {
                    "id": "teams_leader031921",
                    "object": "plan",
                    "active": true,
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "amount": 7900,
                    "amount_decimal": "7900",
                    "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                    "created": 1616186579,
                    "currency": "usd",
                    "interval": "month",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "livemode": true,
                    "metadata": {
                        "maxTeams": "10"
                    },
                    "nickname": "Team Leader Dashboard",
                    "product": "prod_J3PgxhjcFS5hSY",
                    "tiers_mode": null,
                    "transform_usage": null,
                    "trial_period_days": null,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "price": {
                    "id": "teams_leader031921",
                    "object": "price",
                    "active": true,
                    "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                    "created": 1616186579,
                    "currency": "usd",
                    "livemode": true,
                    "lookup_key": null,
                    "metadata": {
                        "maxTeams": "10"
                    },
                    "nickname": "Team Leader Dashboard",
                    "product": "prod_J3PgxhjcFS5hSY",
                    "recurring": {
                        "aggregate_usage": null,
                        "interval": "month",
                        "interval_count": 1,
                        "trial_period_days": null,
                        "usage_type": "licensed"
                    },
                    "tiers_mode": null,
                    "transform_quantity": null,
                    "type": "recurring",
                    "unit_amount": 7900,
                    "unit_amount_decimal": "7900"
                },
                "proration": true,
                "quantity": 1,
                "subscription": "sub_JCqq4Pb9LCeqPt",
                "subscription_item": "si_JCqqKM0mNJwXqR",
                "tax_amounts": [],
                "tax_rates": [],
                "type": "invoiceitem"
            },
            {
                "id": "il_tmp_c014e7ccd7984e",
                "object": "line_item",
                "amount": 7900,
                "currency": "usd",
                "description": "1 × Teams Dashboard (at $79.00 / month)",
                "discount_amounts": [
                    {
                        "amount": 3950,
                        "discount": "di_1IaR98G7MnKgivLUT7aFESCe"
                    }
                ],
                "discountable": true,
                "discounts": [],
                "livemode": true,
                "metadata": {},
                "period": {
                    "end": 1622317969,
                    "start": 1619725969
                },
                "plan": {
                    "id": "teams_leader031921",
                    "object": "plan",
                    "active": true,
                    "aggregate_usage": null,
                    "amount": 7900,
                    "amount_decimal": "7900",
                    "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                    "created": 1616186579,
                    "currency": "usd",
                    "interval": "month",
                    "interval_count": 1,
                    "livemode": true,
                    "metadata": {
                        "maxTeams": "10"
                    },
                    "nickname": "Team Leader Dashboard",
                    "product": "prod_J3PgxhjcFS5hSY",
                    "tiers_mode": null,
                    "transform_usage": null,
                    "trial_period_days": null,
                    "usage_type": "licensed"
                },
                "price": {
                    "id": "teams_leader031921",
                    "object": "price",
                    "active": true,
                    "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
                    "created": 1616186579,
                    "currency": "usd",
                    "livemode": true,
                    "lookup_key": null,
                    "metadata": {
                        "maxTeams": "10"
                    },
                    "nickname": "Team Leader Dashboard",
                    "product": "prod_J3PgxhjcFS5hSY",
                    "recurring": {
                        "aggregate_usage": null,
                        "interval": "month",
                        "interval_count": 1,
                        "trial_period_days": null,
                        "usage_type": "licensed"
                    },
                    "tiers_mode": null,
                    "transform_quantity": null,
                    "type": "recurring",
                    "unit_amount": 7900,
                    "unit_amount_decimal": "7900"
                },
                "proration": false,
                "quantity": 1,
                "subscription": "sub_JCqq4Pb9LCeqPt",
                "subscription_item": "si_JCqqKM0mNJwXqR",
                "tax_amounts": [],
                "tax_rates": [],
                "type": "subscription"
            }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 3,
        "url": "/v1/invoices/upcoming/lines?customer=cus_J9130PfYbywDY7&subscription=sub_JCqq4Pb9LCeqPt&subscription_proration_behavior=create_prorations"
    },
    "livemode": true,
    "metadata": {},
    "next_payment_attempt": 1619729569,
    "number": null,
    "on_behalf_of": null,
    "paid": false,
    "payment_intent": null,
    "payment_settings": {
        "payment_method_options": null,
        "payment_method_types": null
    },
    "period_end": 1619725969,
    "period_start": 1617047569,
    "post_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
    "pre_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
    "receipt_number": null,
    "starting_balance": 0,
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "status": "draft",
    "status_transitions": {
        "finalized_at": null,
        "marked_uncollectible_at": null,
        "paid_at": null,
        "voided_at": null
    },
    "subscription": "sub_JCqq4Pb9LCeqPt",
    "subscription_proration_date": 1617047590,
    "subtotal": 12900,
    "tax": null,
    "total": 8950,
    "total_discount_amounts": [
        {
            "amount": 3950,
            "discount": "di_1IaR98G7MnKgivLUT7aFESCe"
        }
    ],
    "total_tax_amounts": [],
    "transfer_data": null,
    "webhooks_delivered_at": null
}
```

If coupons are taken out of the equation, I can simply combine the first two line items to get the difference between the time on their current plan and the time remaining on the new plan. If there is already a coupon applied to this subscription, those amounts are correct but if I attempt to add a new coupon, those amounts are incorrect.

I've tried submitting the payment and comparing the resulting receipt with the items in the upcoming invoice but I can't see a way to consistently determine the amount due today with a new coupon code.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This (linked image below) is a screenshot of the receipt that is generated. Basically what I want to do is correctly display these amounts (including a newly entered promotion code/coupon)

[Stripe receipt for subscription upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNJ8y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discount is being applied; the details are shown in the `total_discount_amounts` property:

```
    "total_discount_amounts": [
        {
            "amount": 3950,
            "discount": "di_1IaR98G7MnKgivLUT7aFESCe"
        }
    ],
```

Note: the discount is only being applied to a single Invoice Item (`il_tmp_c014e7ccd7984e` in this case).  This is probably why you're not seeing what you expect.

In your question you said:

> I am submitting the coupon to the Stripe invoices.retrieveUpcoming API and the object that is returned has discount information on it but the line items don't show the discounted prices.

If you look at `il_tmp_c014e7ccd7984e` you can see the `amount` is set to `7900` and the `discount_amounts.amount` is set to `3950` which is how the discount is reflected on that line.  If you want the actual amount of that specific line you would subtract `discount_amounts.amount` from `amount`.

Comment: Right. BUT this only tells me what the discounted price will be moving forward. I want to show an accurate amount that the user will have to pay immediately in order to upgrade. The line items show me prorated amounts for the previous and new plans but doesn't apply the coupon to the prorated amount for the new plan and deducting the discounted amount doesn't give me the correct ammount.

Comment: Yep, this is expected, as [prorations are not discountable](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/object#invoiceitem_object-discountable).  You can see in the response the prorated line items have `discountable` set to `false`. See also [the documentation about updating the `discountable` property on an Invoice Item](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/update#update_invoiceitem-discountable).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I didn’t catch that. Can I ask why and it seems like the coupon code is applied to the prorated amount when the upgrade invoice is finalized?

Comment: I believe prorations are not discountable because they happen prior to the coupon being applied (meaning the amount that covers the period before the coupon is applied is, by definition, not covered by the coupon).  I'm not sure what you mean about the prorated amount being discounted when the upgrade Invoice is finalized... might be worth posting a separate question about that with more details?

Comment: That is a good idea. I'm just trying to reconcile the differences I'm seeing between when I submit changes to the upcoming invoice end point and what I'm actually seeing on the receipt when I make that transaction.